# Chartjs not updating with data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am using `react-chartjs-2` and trying to create a line graph from my data.

Currently, I am getting the data from a backend in my main component `App.js` and then passing it as `props` to the `Graph` component.

The data comes into my `Graph` component correctly although it seems like it is rendering multiple times?

The intial data passed to `Graph` looks like the following:

*props.data:*

```js
{
"2020-01-03": "0"
"2020-01-04": "0"
"2020-01-05": "0"
"2020-01-06": "0"
"2020-01-07": "0"
"2020-01-08": "0"
"2020-01-09": "0"
"2020-01-10": "0"
"2020-01-11": "0"
"2020-01-12": "0"
"2020-01-13": "0"
"2020-01-14": "0"
....
}
```

Then in my `Graph` component I split the data into dates and numbers:

```js
let pointData = [];
let dates = [];
for (const property in props.cases) {
  pointData.push(`${props.cases[property]}`);
  dates.push(`${property}`);
}
pointData = pointData.slice(-30);
dates = dates.slice(-30);
console.log(pointData);
console.log(dates)
```

Although when running the above console logs my data is being repeated and emptied occasionally.

[image: repeat]

On the 3rd & 4th last `console.log()` my data is correct, although the other times I am just getting an empty array.

When I then try and render this data to my chart:

*Graph.js*

```js
const data = {
    // this would loop over passed in dates
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
        data: pointData
      }
    ]
  };

    return (
    <div className="vaccine-chart chart">
      <h2>Daily Cases:</h2>
      <Line data={data} />
      </div>
    )
}
```

Nothing appears and no data is rendered.

How can I make my chart render my data correctly? How do I also fix the problem of empty arrays being outputted rather than my actual data?

Comment: I think it's because the length of `labels` and `pointData` for  component `Line` are not equal.

Comment: @ZHANGLuyao Tried that and still not working

Comment: Could you paste the complete code？It may be because the `pointData` is empty at the last render of `Graph` component. You should check the process how data is passed to `Graph` and why the `pointData` is empty.